# ScrollView next to static Layout Element in landscape View

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to divide my fragment UI into two sections, the left half will be a static Image View and the right half will be a scrolling view to show a dynamic list.  I have the following layout
`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/primaryText">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_preview"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#50000000" />

        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_preview">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

`

The problem is that I cant get the ScrollView to scroll, even setting the height programmatically has no effect and the scrollview only shows list items that fit the screen

Comment: because your scroll view contains an listview, listview has its own scroll behaviour

Comment: You sure this thing compiles?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misunderstood what ListView is.

What I see is you are trying to use ListView as a list item while ListView is like a LinearLayout with a Scroll.

Take a look at these two links:

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

[Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)